# c# LinQ Update with multiple where

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I'm stuck in using LinQ, I can update using 1 filter but when using multiple it ignores the other 2 and just check the first one.

Here is the code that I am using:

One where that is working:

```
Engagement_History eh = qdb.Engagement_History.First(a => (a.pdPPMCID.Equals(PPMCID));
```

Multiple Where that is not working:

```
Engagement_History eh = qdb.Engagement_History.First(a => ((a.pdPPMCID.Equals("1")) && (a.ehMonth.Equals("1")) && (year.Equals("2016"))));
```

Comment: What is your definition of _is not working_ ?

Comment: You have just `year.Equals("2016")` shouldn't this be `a.year.Equals("2016")` (or something)? Is this a typo in your question or is this your actual code?

Comment: What exactly is `a` and shouldn't you use a `String.Compare` rather than a `Equal`?

Comment: Does this statement work for you:
`Engagement_History eh = qdb.Engagement_History.Where(a => ((a.pdPPMCID.Equals("1")) && (a.ehMonth.Equals("1")) && (a.year.Equals("2016")))).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Yeah it turns out I forgot the a in year. Thanks @ChrisF. Been Coding for 7 hours straight starting to loose my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query you have just

```
year.Equals("2016")
```

as your final clause.

This should be:

```
a.year.Equals("2016")
```

Otherwise it's going to be looking for a local variable called `year` to compare "2016" against. If that local variable doesn't exist then you should be seeing a compiler error. If it does exist then the query will only return results if it's set to "2016".